# Compare 2 files without reading new line c#

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, compare, string-comparison

how can i compare 2 files without reading newline/Return.There's some case that it didnt compare a new line.
Note : if this code will be tested use many spaces/strings in a file in an array directory .
Example

This is the current Scenario

```
        File 1|File2
        ---   | ---
line1   Hello1|Hello4
line2   Hello1|Hello1
line3         |
line4   Hello2|Hello2
```

The output will be placed on another text file .

```
    Expected Output : 
    FROM File2. Line 1 : Hello4

    Current Output: 
    FROM File2. Line 1  : Hello4
    FROM File2. Line 3  :
```

Code :

```
 for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= arrayrows - 1; ctr++)
        {
            for (int ctr2 = 0; ctr2 <= arraycolumns - 1; ctr2++)
            {


                if (File.Exists(path + @stringArray[ctr, ctr2]))
                {
                    string[] File1Lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + @stringArray[ctr, ctr2]);
                    string[] File2Lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + @stringArray2[ctr, ctr2]);
                    List<string> NewLines = new List<string>();

                    if (File1Lines.Length >= File2Lines.Length)
                    {
                        greaterindex = File1Lines.Length;
                    }
                    else if (File2Lines.Length >= File1Lines.Length)
                    {
                        greaterindex = File2Lines.Length;
                    }

                    for (int lineNo = 0; lineNo <= greaterindex - 1; lineNo++)
                    {

                        if (lineNo > (File2Lines.Length - 1))
                        {
                            NewLines.Add("FROM File1. Line " + lineNo + ": " + File1Lines[lineNo]);
                        }
                        else if (lineNo > (File1Lines.Length - 1))
                        {
                            NewLines.Add("FROM File2. Line " + lineNo + ": " + File2Lines[lineNo]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(File1Lines[lineNo]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(File2Lines[lineNo])) //kapag ung same line sa 2 files hindi null
                            {

                                if (String.Compare(File1Lines[lineNo], File2Lines[lineNo]) != 0)
                                    NewLines.Add("FROM File2. Line " + lineNo + ": " + File2Lines[lineNo]);

                            }
                            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(File1Lines[lineNo])) //kapag ung particular line sa file 2 null
                            {
                            }
                            else //kapag ung particular line sa file 1 null
                            {
                                NewLines.Add("FROM File2. Line " + lineNo + ": " + File2Lines[lineNo]);
                                /*NewLines.Add("==========Discrep Found========");
                                NewLines.Add("FROM File2: " + File2Lines[lineNo]);
                                NewLines.Add("FROM File1: " + File1Lines[lineNo]);
                                NewLines.Add("===============================");*/
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: If you want to compare strings without considering newlines at the ends of the strings, remove the newlines from the ends of the strings.

Comment: Maybe you want `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty`?  That will handle lines that are only whitespace.  That or consider using `Trim` to remove whitespace before comparing.

Comment: The return carriage and new line feed characters should not interfere in this case. I would imagine the ReadAllLines would handle that. I wonder if this may be an encoding/special character issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this part of code instead of your (big `else` block):

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(File1Lines[lineNo]) && 
    !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(File2Lines[lineNo]))
{
    if (String.Compare(File1Lines[lineNo], File2Lines[lineNo]) != 0)
    {
        NewLines.Add("FROM File2. Line " + lineNo + ": " + File2Lines[lineNo]);
        continue;
    }
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(File1Lines[lineNo])) 
{
    NewLines.Add("FROM File1. Line " + lineNo + ": " + File2Lines[lineNo]);
    continue;
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(File2Lines[lineNo])) 
{
    NewLines.Add("FROM File2. Line " + lineNo + ": " + File2Lines[lineNo]);
    continue;
}
```

Use [continue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) statement and [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) method and curly brackets and write all conditions.